# Unable to establish a connection with the SafariDriver during launching Safari with Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, macos, selenium-webdriver, safari, safaridriver

Tried using Selenium with the SafariWebDriver.
Using the jars
selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar - to run the Jetty Server

```
java -jar ./lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar
```

selenium-java-2.33.0.jar
(I didn't use Maven to setup project - just downloaded the jars, and compiled with javac)

```
javac -s ./src -cp ./classes:./lib/selenium-java-2.33.0.jar:./lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar ./src/jgf/Selenium2Example.java -d ./classes
```

Wrote a class which is more or less a copy/paste of the Selenium2Example, but used SafariWebDriver instead of the FirefoxWebDriver

But when the code executes, I get the message in the Safari Web Browser (using Snow Leopard with Safari 5.1.9 (6534.59.8)).

**Unable to establish a connection with the SafariDriver**

Any ideas on how to solve this?

BTW: I'm not using a Safari Extension compiled from source with certificate by signing up as an Apple Developer - I think that applied to earlier jar versions.

Here is the code

```
package jgf;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
//import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Selenium2Example  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
       //WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
       WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        // Alternatively the same thing can be done like this
        // driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        // Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
        // Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("cheese!");
            }
        });

        // Should see: "cheese! - Google Search"
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        //Close the browser
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wondered if it was some sort of firewall issue. So tried disabling that. Then I got some sort of weird exceptions. First this Exception in thread "Thread-3" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to uninstall extension
verExtension$UninstallThread.run(SafariDriverExtension.java:293)  then on subsequent run Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Failed to connect to SafariDriver after 45077 ms

Comment: Saw this related comment - and can confirm using locally http://www.sqaforums.com/forums/selenium/149199-%5Bsafaridriver%5D-safari-can-not-find-element-webpage.html

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with 2.34, so I went back to 2.31 and all seems well, not getting the 'unable to establish a connection' error with safari.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the OS Windows.
Prerequisite: Install Safari on Windows

1. Go to http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/
2. Scroll down -> Go to the section "SafariDriver" and download "SafariDriver.safariextz"
3. Double click on "SafariDriver.safariextz" (previously downloaded)
4. Safari would open with a pop up containing "Install" button -> Click Install button
5. Now go to Preferences of Safari and you would see WebDriver (in my case WebDriver 2.48.0) is installed (Enable WebDriver checkbox is checked))
6. It's now time to instantiate SafariDriver and get the desired URL as below:

   WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
   driver.get("https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/mastering-selenium-testing-tools-video");

Comment: I am using Windows 7